# Parallel.Foreach with localFinally gets stalled despite completing all iterations

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library

In My Parallel.ForEach Loop the localFinally delegate does get called on all the threads.
I have found this to happen as my Parallel Loop stalls.
In my Parallel Loop I have about three condition check stages that return before completion of the Loop. And it seems that it is when the Threads are returned from these stages and not the execution of the entire body that it does not execute the localFinally delegate.

The Loop structure is as follows:

```
 var startingThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
 Parallel.ForEach(fullList, opt,
         ()=> new MultipleValues(),
         (item, loopState, index, loop) =>
         {
            if (cond 1)
                return loop;
            if (cond 2)
                {
                process(item);
                return loop;
                }
            if (cond 3)
                return loop;

            Do Work(item);
            return loop;
          },
          partial =>
           {
              Log State of startingThread and threads
            } );
```

I have run the loop on a small data set and logged in detail and found that while the Parallel.ForEach completes all the iterations and the Log at the last thread of localFinally is --
Calling Thread State is WaitSleepJoin for Thread 6 Loop Indx 16
the Loop still does not complete gracefully and remains stalled... any clues why the stalls ?

Cheers!

Comment: Might be a deadlock somewhere

Comment: Might be just the pseudo code, but cond 3 will never be reached in its current state. the if(cond2) has no parenthesis around the conditions (so only process(item) falls under it).

Comment: @RobertVerpalen No that is just an error in the pseudo code caused by leaving out the parenthesis ...

Comment: Just a quick one, how is the logging mechanism implemented? Could the logging mechanism be the problem? I spent a day once looking for a problem which my slightly faulty logs told me existed (but didn't) =P

Comment: @Brian, thought it would be, had to check anyway. Sorry about that. Seeing the obvious pseudo code I feel rather silly about it now LOL

Comment: How are your conditions evaluated?  Do they do a check, then set a flag/state for subsequent conditions?

Comment: Maybe you just misunderstood what `localFinally` means. It's not called for each item, it's called for each thread that is used by `Paralle.ForEach()`. And many items can share the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did a quick test run after seeing the definition of localFinally (executed after each thread finished), which had me suspecting that that could mean there would be far less threads created by parallelism than loops executed. e.g.

```
        var test = new List<List<string>> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            test.Add(null);
        }

        int finalcount = 0;
        int itemcount = 0;
        int loopcount = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach(test, () => new List<string>(),
            (item, loopState, index, loop) =>
            {
                Interlocked.Increment(ref loopcount);
                loop.Add("a");
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
                return loop;
            },
            l =>
            {
                Interlocked.Add(ref itemcount, l.Count);                    
                Interlocked.Increment(ref finalcount);                    
            });
```

at the end of this loop, itemcount and loopcount were 1000 as expected, and (on my machine) finalcount 1 or 2 depending on the speed of execution. In the situation with the conditions: when returned directly the execution is probably much faster and no extra threads are needed. only when the dowork is executed more threads are needed. However the parameter (l in my case) contains the combined list of all executions.
Could this be the cause of the logging difference?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `Interlocked.Increment` and `Interlocked.Add` methods to avoid possible threaded race conditions with your various counters?

Comment: had them volatile in my local test scenario so they should be thread safe and the results are the same, but for the posted example you're right, some sort of locking should be used

Comment: @RobertVerpalen Marking a field as `volatile` doesn't magically make it thread-safe. In particular, it doesn't mean that `++` will work correctly, because `++` is not atomic.

Comment: Hmmm, then again seems volatile isn't enough, just did a quick check with thread sleep to see the number of threads increase and my loopcount was 987. Changed the code to use the interlocked functions. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @svick, so I noticed, you and Chris are absolutely right! I'll keep that in mind from now on. For all clarity: the results remain the same.

Comment: Glad I got this pointed out to me, not that I've used volatile that much, but I always assumed it was read and write thread safe. After more scrupulous reading of the definition it's clear to me now that it's only meant for one thread to alter and others to read (for none atomic operations). I'll be out checking some old code now, to see if it was ever used incorrectly...

Comment: @RobertVerpalen -- Many Thanks for doing the test that does shed some light on the Parallel.Foreach using the localFinally on each thread that is used ... but I still have the problem with my Loop Stalling -- Calling Thread State is WaitSleepJoin for Thread 6 Loop Indx 16

Comment: Calling Thread State is WaitSleepJoin for Thread 6 Loop Indx 16 is the Log line from the last iteration of the loop so alls getting executed but the loop just stalls and does not relinquish control back to the Calling main thread ...

Comment: I have tried starting off the Parallel.Foreach as a separate task with System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{} but makes no improvement ??

Comment: Calling thread state is done in the localFinally you mean? I'm not entirely sure where is what. Could you perhaps post some more code on what happens inside the loop and localfinally?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just misunderstood what `localFinally` means. It's not called for each item, it's called for each thread that is used by `Parallel.ForEach()`. And many items can share the same thread.

The reason why it exists is that you can perform some aggregation independently on each thread, and join them together only in the end. This way, you have to deal with synchronization (and have it impact your performance) only in a very small piece of code.

For example, if you want to compute the sum of score for a collection of items, you could do it like this:

```
int totalSum = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(
    collection, item => Interlocked.Add(ref totalSum, ComputeScore(item)));
```

But here, you call `Interlocked.Add()` for every item, which can be slow. Using `localInit` and `localFinally`, you can rewrite the code like this:

```
int totalSum = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(
    collection,
    () => 0,
    (item, state, localSum) => localSum + ComputeScore(item),
    localSum => Interlocked.Add(ref totalSum, localSum));
```

Notice that the code uses `Interlocked.Add()` only in the `localFinally` and does access the global state in `body`. This way, the cost of synchronization is paid only a few times, once for each thread used.

Note: I used `Interlocked` in this example, because it is very simple and quite obviously correct. If the code was more complicated, I would use `lock` first, and try to use `Interlocked` only when it was necessary for good performance.

Comment: Many thanks for the Enlightening response ... In my implementation I don't have any use for localFinally except use it for debugging purposes as my parallel.ForEach Loop executes all the iterations but still remains stalled. This is the Log output from localFinally which prints the state of the CurrentThread before invoking the Loop -- Calling Thread State is WaitSleepJoin for Thread 6 Loop Indx 16, but despite completing all the iterations the Parallel.ForEach does not exit gracefully any clues why the Loop will not terminate gracefully ?

Comment: Many thanks for your responses !! I managed to locate the point where the code was blocking in one of the calls and I got the Loop to progress to completion ! Cheers !